# SQL syntax - running stored procedure repeats some rows

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, syntax

I'm very confused with a stored procedure.

The stored procedure - regardless of how I try to use the joins - seems to repeat certain records. It's always the same user every time this procedure is run within the date range 11-1-2017 to 11-30-2017. I'm seriously at a loss here.

I've attached a screenshot showing 1 record repeating at the bottom of the screenshot.

The code here is where I believe the issue lies:

[image]

Code:

```
FROM 
    tbl_Claims
LEFT JOIN 
    tbl_Users ON tbl_Claims.ProvidedBy  = tbl_Users.UserID 
--***12-15-2017***
LEFT JOIN 
    tbl_ClaimDetails ON tbl_Claims.ClaimDetailID  = tbl_ClaimDetails.ClaimDetailID  
LEFT JOIN 
    tbl_Individuals ON tbl_ClaimDetails.IndID = tbl_Individuals.IndID   
--***12-15-2017***
LEFT JOIN 
    tbl_Users ApprovedByJoin ON tbl_ClaimDetails.ApprovedBy = ApprovedByJoin.UserID
LEFT JOIN 
    tbl_Events ON tbl_Claims.InternalEventID = tbl_Events.EventID
LEFT JOIN 
    tbl_Events ted ON tbl_Events.EventID = tbl_Events.EventID
LEFT JOIN 
    tbl_ExpenseType ON tbl_Claims.ExpenseTypeID = tbl_ExpenseType.ExpenseTypeID
LEFT JOIN 
    tbl_Services ON tbl_Claims.ServiceID = tbl_Services.ServiceID
```

Comment: I suggest querying each table where you expect one related record, with an open mind toward finding many. My wild guess is that you'll find this one user/claim has more than one associated event/expensetype/service/etc. associated with it within the date range you're querying.

Comment: I suggest you review the relationships between tables in join, it may be some fields missing somewhere in ON clause

Comment: Thanks to both of you. A co-worker also suggested running a particular claim through each join to find the issue. I didn't even see that someone was joining an alias table on itself. Which ended up being the cause.